# докблоки для yaml в PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, yaml

Итак, в шторме есть поиск, и работает он отлично

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть yaml wiki, примерно такого содержания:

```
Wiki:
    type: object
    properties:
        title:
            $ref: '#/WikiAttributes'
        body:
            $ref: '#/WikiAttributes'
            description: |
                Вики-данные для основного тела страницы. Массив WikiAttribute
        photoAndVideo:
            $ref: '../messageBoard/messageBoard.yaml#/MessageBoard'
            required: false
        questions:
            $ref: '../messageBoard/messageBoard.yaml#/MessageBoard'
            required: true

WikiAttributes:
    type: array
    items:
        $ref: '#/WikiAttribute'
```

и я хочу в докблоке к классу указать прямо ссылку, что смотреть сюда

на данный момент, я делаю это так:

```php
/**
 * @see app2/nuxt-js/openapi/components/wiki/wiki.yaml => Wiki
 */
final class Wiki implements JsonSerializable
{
   /// code
}
```

а хочу такую ссылку, чтобы в шторме yaml файл открывался сразу в нужном месте

Это вообще реально, и если да, то как?

---

Upd. Можно как вариант сделать вот так:

```php
/**
 * @see app2/nuxt-js/openapi/components/wiki/wiki.yaml:14
 */
```

но, если yaml поменяется, все ссылки нужно будет обновлять

P.S это в принципе тоже не проблема, смотреть в файлы я буду нечасто, раз в полгода поправить ссылочку таким путём можно

вопрос в том, можно ли прямо сослаться на объект, тогда докблок будет максимально устойчив к изменениям

---

Comment: На самом деле всё должно работать наоборот. В докблоках вы пишите нужные атрибуты, а специальная генерилка делает из них вики.